# How does one best describe what the TreeSort and HeapSort algorithms are?

Tags: tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, heapsort, treesort

I've read through the wiki page and other StackOverflow answers. Hoping someone can explain what these two algorithms do.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Treesort uses the inorder traversal performed over binary search tree (BST). Building a BST of `n` items take `O(n * depth of tree) = O(n * log n)` time.

Heapsort works on the logic that the largest item is stored at the root of the heap. Building a heap of `n` items take `O(n * each_heapify_TimeComplexity) = O(n * log n)` time.

For screwed tree structure, Treesort's TC would be `O(n^2)`. While Heapsort is **different** in this perspective, as it keeps the depth to minimal possible value by shaping itself as a complete binary tree.